# Local network speed issues, 12.04.01/smb/cifs

Tags: 12.04, networking, samba

I have some very common setup:

- a file server box (12.4.1 / kernel 3.6 / kde) connected to a router box (inet, dhcp).

Wi-Fi router is connected to the first one as DHCP relay. Both are not the best ones, but relatively new; b/g/n modes.

- and devices; like a laptop under latest mint with 3.6 kernel, connected to AP.

All devices are on the same network.

When I run `iperf`, I have speed between them two = 70 Mbit/sec.
When I use samba, a big file is copied at 3.4 Mbit/sec.
When I mount same thing with `cifs`, a big file is copied at 10.4 Mbit/sec.
Ping in between ~3ms.

I haven't tried NFS yet, will do. But the question is: *why would the network speeds differ THAT much?*

I would expect 2x drop, or say 4x drop for some whatever bidirectional something, but that is 20x downspeed - with samba.

*Is it likely something wrong with my setup - or is it some expected result?*

I have couple Windows laptops and would prefer to use something easy compatible like samba - but in my 12.4.1 setup `smbd` crashes few times a day for pattern I could not identify - and "service restart" does not help, so I have to reboot. `Smbd` and `nmbd` logs  do not show anything significant. That did not happen in 11.10.

Now the other question is: *should I keep fighting samba setup, or should I consider some other file sharing option that is easy with Windows?*

Googling did not show any obvious alternative to samba. There is no big load needed on the box - a few guys sharing it as programming/apache/php/etc server, so it just needs to be reasonably quick and reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk performance and network performance are different beasts. `iperf` measures network performance, ie, data speed over LAN. Since there are no disk reads (and, specially, writes) involved, performance is expected to be *many* times greater than *any* file copy. That explains the 70MB/s vs 10MB/s (or 3) difference.

As for "samba vs cifs": first of all, you may have noticed that their performance is "similar", at least in order of magnitude. One is "only" 3x slower, not 20x. And the reason is `cifs` is implemented by the kernel itself, natively, thus much faster than any other fuse-like, user space mount.

Good news is: you *can* use `cifs` to mount devices with the SMB protocol, so your shares are available to windows users. This way you get the best of both worlds: compatibility *and* speed.

An amazing guide from samba.org itself is this: [CIFS Users Guide](http://pserver.samba.org/samba/ftp/cifs-cvs/linux-cifs-client-guide.pdf). You may also read [their great wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Main_Page)

That said, a *wireless* file copy speed of 10MB/s is, from my point of view, very nice.